# Where do I find public JIRA/Greenhopper instance used by Kanban project teams?

Tags: agile, kanban

I'd love to see Atlassian's JIRA/Greenhopper Rapid Board in action, i.e. actively used in a Kanban project.

So far I have not been able to find a public one. Do you know any (e.g. open source) project teams using Greenhopper for Kanban projects?

Thanks in advance for any hints.

P.S: I know I can register for a test account and play around, and already did so, but I would like to see a real world example.

Comment: What are looking to see? How would a real world example be different from what you can create with the test account?

Comment: A real world example displays the tool as it is being used by several users in different roles. Of course, after some playing around I would have populated a test instance with enough data and found the best configuration to work with the tool, but it would be nice to have some inspiration and see how others are using it in actual projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache Software Foundation uses JIRA + Greenhopper and you can [see their installation in action](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/VersionBoard.jspa) without being a committer or having an account. The views should give you an idea of how it's being used in the real world, beyond dummy demo data. It may or may not have all the views you're looking for.

Comment: thx, but only the "old" task, chart, planning and release boards are available. The rapidboard is a special view for kanban, which apache does not seem to use.

Comment: @Huibert I realized that as I was hitting the submit button, then figured an open example of jira + greenhopper might still be useful for someone... :)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, as Huibert pointed out. However, I still have not found a real life example, so I'll accept this as the closest answer. Still interesting to see how the ASF is using JIRA.

Comment: @peterp I think one of the difficulties in finding an example is that a lot of open source projects use Agile but don't use Kanban, because the JIT concept doesn't really work with a relatively loosely organized community working together to produce something.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't spent much time checking this but the Atlassian development teams have public Jira systems, some of those must be using the Rapid Board views. Suprisingly, the Greenhopper team do not appear to have any public Rapid Views available from their project site, but I did find some via the Angry Nerds project.

https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=96

You can browse all the Atlassian projects [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=96) there **must** be some examples of best practice in there, *surely* :-)